# App has been crash when testing on Testflight beta test

Tags: swift, ios7, ios8, cllocationmanager, testflight

I have used the testflight to do the beta test on my app. But it does not work as self-development performance. I have use the google map on my app and it works when i install the app through xcode testing which is run on a real device (iOS 8). However, the app crash when i load the google map on testflight mode.

I have added `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` and `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` into info.plist

code(swift):

```
  if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .NotDetermined
    {
      if (UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion as NSString).floatValue >= 8
      {
        self.manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
      }
    }
```

My development targets are iOS 7 and iOS 8. How can i fix this problem and will it be like this happen on production of iOS 7 and iOS 8?

Comment: Please add crash logs

Comment: Please check your bundled name one you have used for development purpose is you have mention on google but for test flight you have used live bundled so kindly change bundle id name for google map then check

Comment: The bundle name and id is right. The google map is according to the api key to provide services which does not base on the environment.

Comment: @KrunalDarji Do you mean provisioning profile?

Comment: @ShantiK The testflight does not have any crash log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the problem that the environment setting of Linking needs **Other Linker Flags** in **Build Settings** (It is appear in Targets-> your App -> Build Settings) to have parameter **-ObjC** for Google Map SDK. Which i have missed to add the parameter in **Release** environment.